# Converting integer to base 8 using shift operator

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I have a homework problem to convert a user defined 32 bit int to binary using the shift operator. I came up with this code:

```
unsigned int num;
int x = 31;
cout << "Number to be converted: ";
cin >> num;

while (x >= 0)
{
    int y = num >> x;       //using the shift operator
    if (!(y % 2))
        cout << "0";
    else
        cout << "1";
    x--;
}

cout << endl << endl;
```

This runs just fine. The second part of the homework is to elaborate and slightly modify that code to convert a user defined 32 bit int to a base 8 number, again using the shift operator. I can not for the life of me figure out how to make this work.

EDIT: I have already tried a switch and as someone has just commented 
    `cout << (y % 8);` but neither of these options give me the right answer on output.

Comment: you are talking about oop operator overloading?

Comment: Instead of switching on the values of `y % 2`, switch on the values of `y % 8`. And modify how you shift.

Comment: There are 3 bits in each octal digit.

Comment: you can write `if(!(y % 2)) cout << "0"; else cout << "1";` simply as `cout << (y % 2);` now try `(y % 8)` and see how many places you need to shift your `num` in each iteration...

Comment: we can make the observation that base 2 and base 8 have a relationship. If you break a base 2 string by chunks of 3 its easy to make base 8. ex. 10000101 in base 2 goes to 10 000 101 which is 4 0 5 in base 8. Hopefully you can use this to help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note that every three bits of binary give us the corresponding octal value. So we can simply do three shifts and determine the value.

```
while (x >= 0)
{
    int y = num >> x;       //using the shift operator
    x--;
    int z = num >> x;
    x--;
    int a = num >> x;
    x--;
    int total = 4 * y + 2 * z + a;
    cout << total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use shifting and masking:

```
unsigned int value;
unsigned int right_octal_digit = value & 0x07; // Mask off all but lower 3 bits.
unsigned int middle_octal_digit = (value >> 3) & 0x07;
unsigned int left_octal_digit = (value >> 6) & 0x07;
// ... etc.
```

An octal digit uses 3 binary bits.